# One ggplot from two data frames (1 bar each)

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar

I was looking for an answer everywhere, but I just couldn't find one to this problem (maybe I was just too stupid to use other answers, because I'm new to R).

I have two data frames with different numbers of rows. I want to create a plot containing a single bar per data frame. Both should have the same length and the count of different variables should be stacked over each other. For example: I want to compare the proportions of gender in those to data sets.

`t1<-data.frame(cbind(c(1:6), factor(c(1,2,2,1,2,2)))) 
 t2<-data.frame(cbind(c(1:4), factor(c(1,2,2,1))))`

1 represents male, 2 represents female
I want to create two barplots next to each other that represent, that the proportions of gender in the first data frame is 2:4 and in the second one 2:2.

My attempt looked like this:

> ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(1, t1$X2, position = "fill")) + geom_bar(aes(1, t2$X2, position = "fill"))

That leads to the error: "Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic."

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly. You can provide your date by using the function `dput` in order to make your problem reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

First I should merge the two dataframes. You need to add a variable that will identify the origin of the data, add in both dataframes a column with an ID (like t1 and t2). Keep in mind that your columnames are the same in both frames so you will be able to use the function rbind.

```
t1$data <- "t1"
t2$data <- "t2"
t <- (rbind(t1,t2))
```

Now you can make the plot:

```
ggplot(t[order(t$X2),], aes(data, X2, fill=factor(X2))) +        
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```